# What does "no new ground being broken" mean?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man, spider-man-no-way-home

In *Spider Man: No Way Home* (2021), Happy startled Peter Parker, who speaking to MJ on phone:

> Happy: Wrap it up. You both like each other. We get it. Hang up.
> There's **no new ground being broken**. I need my eight hours.

What does "no new ground being broken" mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"[Breaking new ground](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/broken+new+ground)":

> To advance, innovate, or pioneer (something).

In other words, nothing is advancing in their relationship from their phone call. They're just at a lovey-dovey equilibrium.

Comment: The basic point is that Happy wants to go to sleep, but Peter's conversation with his girlfriend is keeping him awake.  So it's not a commentary on Peter and M.J.'s relationship in particular; it's just expressing Happy's annoyance that the conversation won't end.  He's saying "Okay, we all get it, you love each other, shut up and let me sleep."